# How to create a cache in node.js that handles explicitly for simultaneous duplicate requests for a CPU-bound operation

Tags: node.js

So node is working great for me. I have a very specific server application that basically accepts requests to perform a particular CPU-bound procedure, and it executes a C program to do so. Thing is, if I have multiple clients, it's very likely I'll get multiple versions of the same request. It would be a nice optimization to somehow handle for that explicitly, by implementing a cache with something of a lock on a particular key, so that other clients will simply wait on that request coming back, and copy its response.

But I'm new to node, so I don't know how to rig this into my basic node router-request handler mechanism. Obviously I could do it in language x using basic concurrency primitives, but I know that node is event-oriented and I think this could be done quite elegantly in an evented way. Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Several answers above, but none really treating paralel requests to the same resource correctly.

You don't need to worry about concurrency when checking for cache key, since node is a single-threaded environment. All your actions are indeed atomic. All async operations in node will however cause it to accept further requests. Thus you need to handle concurrent overlapping requests, here solved with registering observers to an EventEmmiter:

```js
var http = require('http'), EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var cache = {};

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   var key = someMagic(req), cached = cache[key]; // get some unique request identifier

   if (!cached) { // if we've never seen this request before
     cached = new EventEmitter(); // make this cache entry an event emitter
     cached.status = 'running';
     handleAsyncRequest(function(result) { // your request handling is probably asynchronous, call this callback when you're done
       cached.response = result; // memoize data
       cached.status = 'finished';
       cached.emit('finished'); // notify all observers waiting for this request
     });

   } else {
     switch(cached.status) { // if existing request, check if it's still running or finished
       case 'finished':
         res.end(cached.response); // send cached response immediately if request has finished
         break;
       case 'running':
         // subscribe as observer; send response when request is finished
         cached.once('finished', function() { res.end(cached.response); });
         break;
     }
   }
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the client-side world of JavaScript, you typically cache items in an array.  I am a new to node as well, so pardon if this is not the answer you are looking for, but it's worth a try.

You could set up an empty array when the server starts and store results in with a special hash of some sort based on the request received. This seems like a viable solution.

E.g.

```
var http = require('http');
var cache = [];
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   var obj; 
   if(!cache[key]) {
      obj = .... // logic that gets results
      cache[obj.key] = obj;
    } else {
      obj = cache[key];
    }
}).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track, my main concern is whether I need to handle for concurrency when checking the array for the key, and how to handle waiting for the response to come back if the key is registered but the value isn't yet available. what i really need is a concurrency mechanism of some kind coupled with a way to register an event for clients to wake up when the value becomes available. that's the part i'm really stuck on

Comment: guess I could have the cache that maintains an event emitter for each key to allow you to register? then i just have to deal with concurrency

Answer (score 0):

Easy peasy.. Node.js is single threaded, so that first CPU bound request is blocking the server anyway.. so memoize the results.  Essentially, you set up a hash with the requested key, and before calling the C program, check the hash.  If its there, return it, your're done.  If it's not, run the C program, stick the results in the hash at the requested key before returning, *then* return.

Comment: yeah man i grok what a cache is but the problems is consistency. i've been taught to think about any possible "ordering" but i don't understand node's scheduling well enough. are you saying all operations are atomic? i.e. i don't need to worry about thread A request, thread A starting job, thread B request, thread B starting job, thread A returns, updates cache, thread B returns, updates cache. See what I mean?

Comment: No threads.  Well, okay, *1* thread.  Hence, all events are cooperatively scheduled.  That's why you gotta be careful about event handlers that do a lot; it's got the 'floor' for as long as it wants, until it returns.  So, Request A comes in, Request A starts processing, Request B comes in, but the event loop hasn't come back, so request B stays in the socket's queue until Request A's handler returns.